# How to Get Query Plan During Execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is it possible to capture the query text of the entire RPC SELECT statement from within the view which it calls?  I am developing an enterprise database in SQL Server 2014 which must support a commercial application that submits a complex SELECT statement in which the outer WHERE clause is critical.  This statement also includes subqueries against the same object (in my case, a view) which do NOT include that condition.  This creates a huge problem because the calling application is joining those subqueries to the filtered result on another field and thus producing ID duplication that throws errors elsewhere.

The calling application assumes it is querying a table (not a view) and it can only be configured to use a simple WHERE clause.  My task is to implement a more sophisticated security model behind this rather naive application.  I can't re-write the offending query but I had hoped to retrieve the missing information from the cached query plan.  Here's a super-simplified psuedo-view of my proposed solution:

```
CREATE VIEW schema.important_data AS
WITH a AS (SELECT special_function() AS condition),
     b AS (SELECT c.criteria 
           FROM a, lookup_table AS c 
           WHERE a.condition IS NULL OR c.criteria = a.condition)
SELECT d.field_1, d.field_2, d.filter_field 
FROM b, underlying_table AS d
WHERE d.filter_field = b.criteria;
```

My "special function" reads the query plan for the RPC, extracts the WHERE condition and preemptively filters the view so it always returns only what it should.  Unfortunately, query plans don't seem to be cached until *after* they are executed.  If the RPC is made several times, my solution works perfectly -- but only on the second and subsequent calls.

I am currently using *dm_exec_cached_plans*, *dm_exec_query_stats* and *dm_exec_sql_text* to obtain the full text of the RPC by searching on spid, plan creation time and specific words.  It would be so much better if I could somehow get the currently executing **plan**.  I believe *dm_exec_requests* does that but it only returns the current **statement** -- which is just the definition of my function.

Extended Events look promising but unfamiliar and there is a lot to digest.  I haven't found any guidance, either, on whether they are appropriate for this particular challenge, whether a notification can be obtained in real time or how to ensure that the Event Session is always running.  I am pursuing this investigation now and would appreciate any suggestions or advice.  Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be an untenable idea and I have devised a less elegant work-around by restructuring the view itself.  There is a performance penalty but the downstream error is avoided.  My fundamental problem is the way the client application generates its SQL statements and there is nothing I do about that -- so, users will just have to accept whatever limitations may result.